# Find Density and/or Height of a Storm Cloud in a given Location

Tags: weather

I'm looking for a place that can provide either Historical or Current information about clouds. I'd like it to provide information about the Density of a cloud and the Height of a cloud - this would specifically apply to storm clouds. I've found that some API's provide cloud cover but this does not contain such information I need.

Comment: The ish-format-document.pdf file in ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/ suggests that the ISD has cloud ceiling level data (height of lowest clouds), which might provide you with a start. METAR also sometimes contains the data you need, and https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/download.phtml lets you download an archive of those.

Comment: Please post as an answer @BarryCarter

Comment: Neither of these actually gives you a complete answer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh, ok, well thank you for the links, I'll see what I can gather from just that resource I guess